# Problem in obtaining the focus of JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecelleditor

This is the scenario: 
I have a JTable of nxn. In the Col(0) of each cell, have a slider with two thumbs each for min and max,two JTextField to represent min and max.

Whenever i click for first time on the cell, slider doesn't responds but on the second click the slider responds.

My guess is that on the first click the JTable gets the focus and on the second click the cell.

would like the cell to respond on the first click.

Thank you on advance...

Comment: You should pose some code to make your problem clear.

Answer (score 4):

set `setClickCountToStart(1)`, more descriptions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=setclickcounttostart)

Answer (score 0):

As I didn't see your code, I guess it's the FocusTraTraversalPolicy that is causing your problem.

In each container of Swing, the components have a predefined order of getting focus. They get the focus in order when you press the Tab button on the keyboard. So when you first click a container, there's a default component that gets the focus, if you're not satisfied with it, you can use the FocusTraversalPolicy to modify it.

Check [this lnk](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html) out, it may help you.